# How to force pull / checkout branch that was recreated on origin?

Tags: git

I have a release branch I call `latest` and I can easily recreate it from a tagged release e.g.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b latest v1.0.1
```

I needed to revert `latest` to a previous release tag due to bugs, then:

- deleted the `latest` branch from the origin
- recreated the `latest` branch from an older tagged release:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b latest v1.0.0
git push origin latest
```

Now in other clones of this repository when someone does a git pull of latest doesn't get the new `latest` that is in the origin (and which is not a continuation of the local `latest`) git simply ignores the request and leaves the local checkout unchanged.

The only way I could find to make this work was to first delete the local copy of branch `latest` and re-pull the branch from the origin.

```
git checkout master
git branch -d latest
git fetch --all
git checkout latest
```

How can I force pull full refresh / overwrite the local branch with the copy from origin without having to delete the local checkout first?

Comment: Why would you make "latest" as a branch? Why not have it as a tag instead? I don't think what you want is possible - it's simply not the way branches are meant to be used, imo

Comment: @fredrik because then I have a predictable and easy way to find the latest released version of my project. Otherwise you would need to find the latest tag release depending on some ordering.

Comment: @fredrik I don't think tags are really meant to be moved frequently.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Neither are branches in this manner. At least a tag would be updated on pull.

Comment: @SkyWalker imo the only predictable, and easy, way to find the latest version is to always find the one with the highest version number. If a change needs to be rolled back - create a new bug fix with a higher version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

If you must do this, use detached-HEAD mode.  Have users check out `origin/latest` rather than creating a branch.

(It's probably wiser to just make a new release-candidate tag.  See [fredrik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934394/how-to-force-pull-checkout-branch-that-was-recreated-on-origin#comment120075130_67934394).)

#### Long

Git "dislikes it" when branch names "move backwards".<sup>1</sup>

What I mean by this is that a branch name is expected to "move forwards", and what I mean by *that* is ... well, consider how Git branch names work.  The purpose of a branch name is to locate the *last* commit that we call "part of the branch".  It is the *commits themselves* that actually matter; the branch name just finds the *last* one.

That is, we might start with a series of, say, eight total commits, which we label with the name `master` or `main`:

```
A <-B <- ... <-G <-H   <--main
```

Each commit has some big ugly random-looking hash ID as its "true name"; for graph-drawing purposes, we replace these with single uppercase letters.<sup>2</sup>  Each commit stores a snapshot of all files, plus the hash ID(s) of some earlier commit(s).  Ordinary commits store only one such hash ID, which builds this kind of simple, linear chain of commits.  Git then works *backwards:* the branch name, `main` in this case, supplies the hash ID of the *last* commit `H`.  That commit supplies the hash ID of an earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G` supplies another still-earlier commit hash ID, and so on, all the way down to commit `A`.  Commit `A` is the very first commit and therefore supplies *no* hash ID at all, and this is where Git stops.

To keep the drawings easier to draw, I tend to draw the connecting, backwards-pointing arrows as lines:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

No commit can ever be changed, not even a single bit, once it has been made, so all arrows necessarily point backwards: when we make commit `G` we have no idea what hash ID `H` will have, but when we make `H`, we know exactly what commit hash ID `G` had.

But look at how we got here.  We started with fewer commits, e.g.:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

Then we did a `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, to get "on" branch `main`, as `git status` would say.  Then we made a new commit, `E`.  In the middle of making this commit, we have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
          \
           E
```

New commit `E` points back to existing commit `D`.  The final act of `git commit`, here, is to *write the hash ID of `E` into the name `main`:*

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
```

Git knows to do this because the special name `HEAD` is "attached to" the name `main`.  That's part of what `git checkout` or `git switch` is for: it not only extracts the *snapshot* from the commit we select, it also *attaches `HEAD`* to some branch name.<sup>3</sup>

Similarly, as we make new commits `F`, `G`, and `H`, the branch name advances, one commit at a time:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- main
```

and so on.

Now, we—as the person running `git` locally, in our own repository—are allowed, with `git reset` and `git branch -f` and several other less-user-oriented commands,<sup>4</sup> to "move" a branch name arbitrarily.  That is, given:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- main
                   \
                    H--I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

we can forcibly move `main` with `git branch -f`, or forcibly move `develop` with `git reset`.  We can pick any of the existing ten commits to make either name point to that commit.  For instance, `git branch -f main hash-of-C` results in:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

No *commits* have changed, but we "rewound `main`" by forcing the branch name backwards.  Commits `D` through `H` used to be on *both* branches, and are now only on `develop`.

When one Git contacts another Git, with `git fetch` or `git push`, the two Gits:

- exchange commits: the sending Git sends the receiving Git whatever commits it may need, to complete the transaction; then
- for `git push`, the sender asks the receiver to please, if it's OK, create or update his *branch names*, giving the receiver hash IDs and branch names;
- for `git fetch`, the sender supplies all his branch names and hash IDs, and the receiver creates or updates his *remote-tracking names*.

The middle step—the one that uses the *please, if it's OK* part—is central to `git push`: the *receiver* decides whether this is OK.  Git allows each receiver to run arbitrary scripts that can make fine-grained decisions for each name (branch name, tag name, etc.); but even without this, Git will *automatically reject* a request that would move a name "backwards" the way we did with `main` above.<sup>5</sup>

When using `git fetch`, the receiver is the client.  The default here is to force-update all the remote-tracking names, so that `origin/main` can easily "move backwards" like this.  That's fine, but note that **this does not affect the receiver's *branch* names, such as `main`**.  It only affects the receiver's *remote-tracking* names.  It's then up to the Git user to notice that `main` moved backwards, and to move his own `main` backwards if necessary.

Users who use `git pull` to run `git merge` automatically, following this kind of backwards remote-tracking-name update, *will not lose the commits that you want them to lose*.  That is, they'll still have all the commits that you sent them earlier, that they added to *their* branch.  Their Git will not drop these commits, in case they're using them.

**What this all boils down to is "don't do that".**  If you *do* need to do that—if it makes something easier—make sure *none of your users create a local branch of the same name*.  Instead, they should use "detached HEAD" mode with `origin/latest`.  Otherwise, they need to understand how commit-removal works when moving branch names backwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers—they hate that!

<sup>2</sup>This means our graph-drawing is limited to about 26 commits, depending on the alphabet we use.  That's why real hash IDs are big and ugly, or at least, part of why.

<sup>3</sup>With `--detach`, it puts Git into *detached HEAD* mode, which is mainly used internally by the `git rebase` code, but which you can also use to poke around with historic commits.  Here `HEAD` holds the raw hash ID of some commit, instead of holding a branch name.  That's how Git knows that you are in this detached-HEAD mode: `HEAD` holds a hash ID instead of a branch name.  If `HEAD` holds a branch name, that's the branch you're on, and the branch name itself finds the commit.  So when making a new commit, Git need only update *one* name: either `HEAD` itself, if detached, or the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached, if attached.

<sup>4</sup>The `git reset` command is so overpowered that I don't really like to think of it as "user-oriented", but it's what Git has at the moment.  Just as `git checkout` was overpowered, and got split into `git switch` and `git restore`, I think `git reset` could stand to be split up.  However, much of its lower-powered mode would just be `git restore` so there is little impetus for doing this among the Git maintainers.

<sup>5</sup>You can use `git push --force` to turn the polite request into a command, but the receiving Git can deny the command.  All of this depends on the scripts, if any, at the receiving end.  The sender here deliberately has very little control: he can only set the force flag, to bypass the standard built-in "fast forward only" check, and in modern Git, provide environment variables that scripts can inspect.